# Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. Then the number of positive integer solutions of the equation $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{pq}$$ are:

I have no idea how to start. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps clearing the fractions will yield some insight?

Comment: Start with examples.  Take $(p,q)=(2,3)$ or $(3,5)$.

Comment: These might help [Number of positive integer solutions of $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{pq}$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095007/number-of-positive-integer-solutions-of-frac1x-frac1y-frac1pq-f), [Solve $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}=\dfrac{1}{pq}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343056/solve-dfrac1x-dfrac1y-dfrac1pq).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply with $xypq$:
$$\tag1 ypq+xpq=xy$$
It follows that $ypq$ is a multiple of $x$ and $xpq$ is a multiple of $y$.
Say, $ypq=ax$, $xpq=by$. Then $yp^2q^2=axpq=aby$, i.e., there are only few possibilities for $a,b$, namely $a\in\{1,p,p^2,q,pq,p^2q,q^2,pq^2,p^2q^2\}$ and $b=p^2q^2/a$.
In particular, dividing $(1)$ by $x$ or $y$ gives $a+pq=y$, $pq+b=x$. All in all, we have found nine solutions:
$$\begin{align}\frac1{pq}&=\frac1{pq+1}+\frac1{pq+p^2q^2}\\
&=\frac1{pq+p}+\frac1{pq+pq^2}\\
&=\frac1{pq+p^2}+\frac1{pq+q^2}\\
&=\frac1{pq+q}+\frac1{pq+p^2q}\\
&=\frac1{pq+pq}+\frac1{pq+pq}\\
&=\frac1{pq+p^2q}+\frac1{pq+q}\\
&=\frac1{pq+q^2}+\frac1{pq+p^2}\\
&=\frac1{pq+pq^2}+\frac1{pq+p}\\
&=\frac1{pq+p^2q^2}+\frac1{pq+1}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that we have $x | pqy$ and $y | pqx$. So write $pqy=tx$ and $pqx=sy$. From this find all possibilities of $s,t$. Then along with these equations and $pq(x+y)=xy$. Show that there are only 4 distinct solutions $x=p(1+q), y=qx$ etc. (2 if you don't distinguish between $x,y$).